# google Drive via Resumable upload Request fails returning error code 12156.if any one know about this please reply?

Tags: c, winapi, windows-10, winhttp, drive

On windows-10 while uploading file to google Drive via Resumable upload Request fails.
WinhttpReceiveResponce() Fails with return code 12156.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, found the answer. On windows 10 WinhttpReceiveResponce() function unnecessary fails returning 12156 ERROR_WINHTTP_REDIRECT_FAILED(i.e. either Windows change policy or you  all attempts failed(5)).

So on windows 10, in case of chunk data uploading to google drive don't check the return value of WinhttpReceiveResponce().go ahed. so when i skip the return value then file get uploaded successfully.

so i take the meaning of change of policy is that windows change its policy for windows 10 in case of requesting server don't know its right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 years this question is still actual, I ran into the same problem using C++ REST SDK.

As Google Drive REST API stated:

> A `308 Resume Incomplete` response indicates that you need to continue
>   uploading the file.

But when Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016 encounter HTTP response code 308 it raises WinHTTP error 12156 (`ERROR_WINHTTP_REDIRECT_FAILED`) for some reason.

So, using a resumable upload you should treat `ERROR_WINHTTP_REDIRECT_FAILED` as `308 Resume Incomplete` while ran on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016.